# What should I use Sleep or Timer

Tags: c#, timer, sleep

I have two alternative using timer or using sleep, I need to call a method every 3 seconds after this method is finished, I wrote basic example to demonstrate what I mean:

```
public static void Main()
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(fooUsingSleep)).Start();

    callToMethodAfterInterval(new Action<object, ElapsedEventArgs>(fooUsingTimer), 3000);
}

public static void fooUsingSleep()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing some consuming time work using sleep");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    fooUsingSleep();
}

public static void fooUsingTimer(object dummy, ElapsedEventArgs dummyElapsed)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing some consuming time work usning timer");
    callToMethodAfterInterval(new Action<object, ElapsedEventArgs>(fooUsingTimer), 3000);
}

public static void callToMethodAfterInterval(Action<object,ElapsedEventArgs> inMethod, int inInterval)
{
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(inMethod);
    myTimer.Interval = inInterval;
    myTimer.AutoReset = false;
    myTimer.Start();
}
```

So my questions are

1)Can I wrote the code with the timer more elegant? Means removing the call to the callToMethodAfterInterval method from fooUsingTimer, make the timer one or two lines, and remove the dummy variables from the declaration of fooUsingTimer?

2)I understand sleep isn't busy waiting (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ThreadingDotNet.aspx)
So I don't found justification to use the timer option here, because the sleep is more simple, what is better to use, the timer version or the sleep one?

3)I know that Timers.timer is thread safe, does it can help me in the behavior I want to implement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real context of your program matters too.

The sleep option 'wastes' a Thread, not a problem in a small console app but in general not a good idea.

You don't need to restart the timer, the following will keep ticking:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        t.Elapsed += (s, e) => CallMeBack();
        t.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I would note that I don't think that this is exactly what the original was meant to be doing - it was doing it's long running task and then running it again 3 seconds after completion - yours will run every second?

Comment: @Paddy, right, I was assuming a relativel short task. The OP should tell.

Comment: I don't want the option foo will be called before the other calls to foo has finished..

Comment: @Delas: Then some sort of guard flag would be best (if Foo() can come even close to 3 sec).

Comment: Sound good to me, mark as answer, I also liked you eliminate the need to declare the dummy variables in the foo declaration

Answer (score 3):

Do you realize that `fooUsingSleep` is calling itself over and over? It will eventually generate a stack overflow.

If you are using timer, it can be as simple as this:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    t.Interval = 3000;
    t.Tick += new EventHandler((o,ea) => Console.WriteLine("foo"));
```

Comment: +1 for elegant solution, how it will cause stack overflow? I can't see it, in your solution the method can be called before the last one has finished and it can lead to hard bugs to find, so this reason I didn't mark as answer

Comment: it cannot be called before the last one has finished because they run on the same thread. Your solution (calling  fooUsingSleep() from inside fooUsingSleep() will eventually overflow the stack because on each method call the execution context is pushed onto a stack, which is not of unlimited capacity)

Comment: Ok, now I understand the stack overflow you mention :)

Answer (score 0):

Sleep will do the trick, Timer on the other hand has been designed for that exact purpose, conventions are better and they will usually make your code more understandable.

Comment: How can I write the timer part more elegant?